# constructor Service in class javax.xml.ws.Service cannot be applied to given types

Tags: service, jax-ws

I have created a web service with apache-cxf-2.7.4.
I entered the classes produced in my project.
the libraries I have in my project are:

- math3-commons-3.2.jar
- XStream-1.4.4.jar
- jaxws-api-2.2.5.jar

I have the following error:

```
  constructor Service in class javax.xml.ws.Service cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.net.URL,javax.xml.namespace.QName
  found: java.net.URL,javax.xml.namespace.QName,javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature[]
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Answer (score 11):

The problem is the version of JAX-WS API. The classloader for your application first loaded the version included in Java SE or Java EE.

For Java SE 6 or Java EE 5, JAX-WS API 2.1. The constructors in [`javax.xml.ws.Service`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html):

```
javax.xml.ws.Service.Service(URL, QName)
```

For Java SE 7 or Java EE 6, JAX-WS API 2.2. The constructors in [`javax.xml.ws.Service`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html):

```
javax.xml.ws.Service.Service(URL, QName)
javax.xml.ws.Service.Service(URL, QName, WebServiceFeature...)  // You need this!
```

There are three possible solutions (depends on whether it is a web application or standalone application):

1. Use Java SE 7 or Java EE 6.
2. Re-run `wsdl2java` with argument `-frontend jaxws21` to generate JAX-WS 2.1 compliant code instead.
3. Change the classloader for load first the classes included in the application.

Answer (score 2):

If using Maven to build you should add this to the execution configuration

```
<defaultOptions>
    <extraargs>
        <extraarg>-frontend</extraarg>
        <extraarg>jaxws21</extraarg>
    </extraargs>
</defaultOptions>
```

(thanks to Paul Vargas for pointing me in the right direction).

Answer (score 1):

wsimport -help tells us about the -target option. It says: 
Generate code as per the given JAXWS spec version. Defaults to 2.2, Accepted values are 2.0, 2.1 and 2.2

If you are using jdk wsimport tool, then just add the -target argument like below.

wsimport -keep -d \myDirToStoreExtractedClientCode -target 2.1 \myWSDLlocation\mineNotYours.wsdl

(Thanks Paul Vargas for helping out, old post but still helpful.)