# cannot find symbol: constructor Service(java.net.URL,javax.xml.namespace.QName,javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature[]) location: class javax.xml.ws.Service

Tags: java, maven

```
[INFO]  .................................................. SUCCESS [1.166s]
[INFO] aopencommon .................................... FAILURE [3.797s]
```

[INFO] abbuclt ............................ SKIPPED
   .......................... etc all others skipped
   and error below appears
   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
3.2:compile (default-compile) on project aopencommon: Compilation failure: Co
    mpilation failure:
    [ERROR] \Users\ds\Desktop\MYWORKSPACES2\atime\common-jar\src\main\jav
    a\com\ax\id\atec_business_1\ABunes.java:[46,8] cannot find sy
    mbol
    [ERROR] symbol  : constructor Service(java.net.URL,javax.xml.namespace.QName,jav
    ax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature[])
    [ERROR] location: class javax.xml.ws.Service
    ............................................................ etc..

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    4.0.0
    com.acm.ax
    aopenall
    pom
    
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

```
<modules>
  <module>abusjb-jar</module>
  <module>abusear</module>
  <module>aconejb-jar</module>
  <module>aconear</module>
    <module>common-jar</module>
    <module>rerouteservlet-war</module>
    <module>homevalejb-jar</module>
    <module>homevalear</module>
    <module>smallbusejb-jar</module>
    <module>smallbusear</module>
    <module>canbusejb-jar</module>
    <module>canbusear</module>
    <module>canconejb-jar</module>
    <module>canconear</module>
    <module>iscrejb-jar</module>
    <module>iscrear</module>
    <module>informaticaclientejb-jar</module>
    <module>informaticaclientear</module>
    <module>instantauditejb-jar</module>
    <module>instantauditear</module>
    <module>batchlookupservlets-war</module>
    <module>batchlookupejb-jar</module>
    <module>batchlookupear</module>
</modules>
```

below is from comman-jar project pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    
        aopenall
        com.acm.ax
        0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    
    4.0.0
    com.acm.ax
    aopencommon
    jar
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    aopencommon

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.jbossws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbossws-native-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.GA</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.sun.istack</groupId>        
        <artifactId>istack-commons-runtime</artifactId>      
        </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Hi, can you give some information about what happened before that error message occurred?

Comment: first time I run mvn clean install (created .m2) then I got error below: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
3.2:compile (default-compile) on project aopencommon: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR]\Users\dsozer\Desktop\MYWORKSPACES\aRtC611\common-jar\src
\main\java\com\a\id\a_bu\_1\ABu.java:[46,8] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : constructor Service(java.net.URL,javax.xml.namespace.QName,jav
ax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature[])
[ERROR] location: class javax.xml.ws.Service   errors continue..

Comment: my settings are  echo %JAVA_HOME% C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45 and maven version apache-maven-3.0.5

Comment: i did some research and tried to added <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-   plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.6</source>
     <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins> it did not worked then i download the maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.2.jar and tried to install it installed successfully ,then i run mvn clean install and got the error in my first post. not sure whats is going on .

Comment: I also installed 3.1 version of that jar and tried clean install again but did not work either. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try deleting everything from the `.m2/repository/org/apache/maven` dir. Then rebuild your project

Comment: i deleted and got this [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project amexopencommon: Could not resolve depe
ndencies for project com.acxiom.amex:amexopencommon:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed t
o collect dependencies for [org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3
.1 (compile), javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:1.1 (provided), org.jboss.jbossws:jbossws
-native-core:jar:3.1.1.GA (provided), com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:jar:2.2 (provided)
,

Comment: javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0 (provided), org.hibernate:hibernate-
core:jar:3.6.0.Final (provided), junit:junit:jar:3.8.1 (test), log4j:log4j:jar:1
.2.16 (provided)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven
-core:jar:2.2.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-core:pom:2.2
.1 from/to central

Comment: (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://r
epo.maven.apache.org refused: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Answer (score 0):

try to compile with java 7 or use maven-compiler-plugin-2.1.1 instead

Edit:
add to your pom file to override the default compilation

```
<defaultOptions>
<extraargs>
    <extraarg>-frontend</extraarg>
    <extraarg>jaxws21</extraarg>
</extraargs>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17651644/2593751

Comment: hi i tried this with 2.1 ,2.0 but im still getting failed to execute goal 2.3.2 compile (default-compile) on project a : compilation failure .

Comment: can you post your pom.xml file and did you use proxy or did you use M2E should you compile your program in jdk6 please add detail to your question

Comment: @mohannd I added root pom.xml which has just modules and common-jar projects pom.xml which is related with the error. ty

Comment: unfoturnately I need to build with using maven 3(btw i used all available maven 3 versions) and java6 is because all system using java 6 , so using java  7 wont be solution . i tried with maven 2 just for curiosity and having more import declarations not supported errors.

Comment: @mohannd i tried ur depen. suggestion (javaee) but did not work . I changed the error msg above on the top. it fails on aopencommon and then i run mvn dependency:list command then i got error below

Comment: [INFO]  ..................................... SUCCESS [5.123s]
[INFO] aopencommon .......................... SUCCESS [0.648s]
[INFO] abbuclt  ............................ FAILURE [3.417s]
[INFO]  ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] abbuconclt  ............................ SKIPPED

Comment: ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project abbuclt : Could not reso
lve dependencies for project com.ax.abbuc:abbuclt :
jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.acxiom.am:aopencommon:jar:0.0.1-SNA
PSHOT in https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in
 the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update inter
val of jboss-public-repository-group has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help
1]

Comment: it passes aopencommon and get failure on abbuclt .the aopencommon jar downloaded. ,then when ever i run mvn clean install after this error . i got the same error on the top. i tried to add dependencies and install aopencommon jar ,but got the same error on top. im getting this error on comment when i run  mvn dependency:list  . any sugggestion?  thx

Comment: Next time put the actual error into the title. Be specific.

Answer (score 0):

See if you have installed the jdk for that go to: `-> Java Build Path -> Libraries`
If not, download and install it and add it on `Add Library -> JRE System Library -> Alternate JRE: installed JREs -> Add -> Standard VM -> next -> Directory`
In my case the path is: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.fc20.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here today: For me the issue was that the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` was not set. You have to set it to your sdk installation

How to do that (assuming you have a jdk installed):

1. Win + Pausekey
2. Click on "Advanced" on the left
3. Click the "Environment Variables" button
4. set or create a variable with the name `JAVA_HOME` and set it's value accordingly - usually something like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`